# Renaming logical names with variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to rename files logical names with variable. The problem is not the query in variable @ndfnameold, because if I put the simple string, i'll get same error.

```
DECLARE @ndfnameold Nvarchar(MAX)
SET @ndfnameold =  (SELECT name from [sys].[database_files] where physical_name like '%ndf')
DECLARE @query varchar(MAX)

SET @query = 'ALTER DATABASE [MYDATABASE] MODIFY FILE ( NAME =  '+ @ndfnameold +', NEWNAME = MYDATABASE_1_Data )'

EXEC(@query)
```

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '-'.

I don't get whats wrong with this. SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there's no `-` in the rest of your SQL, we can infer that there is one in the old logical file name. Since `-` isn't an [allowed character for a Regular Identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-2017#rules-for-regular-identifiers), we'll have to delimit it.

Safest is to use the [`QUOTENAME` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that will delimit the name whilst respecting escaping rules if other characters are also problematic:

```
SET @query = 'ALTER DATABASE [MYDATABASE] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = ' +
             QUOTENAME(@ndfnameold) +
             ', NEWNAME = MYDATABASE_1_Data )'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answering. Yes, there is -  in the old logical file name. I tried to use QUOTENAME() as you posted but still the same error message.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '-'.